# How to deal with a PHP session timeout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got an area of a webpage which displays a timesheet and the user can click left and right to go forward / back a week:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var TimesheetOffset = 0;
 function TimesheetNav(AdjustBy) {
   TimesheetOffset = TimesheetOffset + AdjustBy;
   $("#timesheets").load("populate_timesheets.php?start=" + TimesheetOffset);
 }
</script>
```

The `populate_timesheets.php` script displays the timesheet information in a DIV area with the id of "timesheets", but only if the user is logged in and their session hasn't expired - if the session has expired it displays a login page:

```
    if (!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
        header("location: index.php");
    }
```

The problem is that if the session has timed-out, the `index.php` script appears where the timesheet should be displayed rather than replacing the entire page. How can I alter either the PHP or the JavaScript so that if the session has timed-out the login page replaces the entire page?

Comment: You could change `$("#timesheets").load()` to something which you can then handle the response code. you could also poll the server to keep the session alive or to redirect in case of timeout.. also you can change the gc on the session to make it stay for longer. many things what have you tried so far?

Comment: You can not redirect the “frontend” from a background request. You need to do this _in_ the frontend, meaning redirect to the login page using JavaScript. So your server-side script only has to return a _value_ to your JavaScript that it can base this decision on. And that probably means that you do not want to use .load in the first place, because that does not have that kind of functionality build-in. So a “normal” AJAX request might be the better choice here, it gives you more flexibility to react to the two different cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax("populate_timesheets.php?start=" + TimesheetOffset, {
   type: "GET",
   statusCode: {
      401: function (response) {
         // redirect to login page
      }
   }, 
   success: function (data) {
      $( "#timesheets" ).html(data);
   },
   error: function (error) {
      console.log('Error occured: ', error);
   }
});
```

PHP code:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
    return;
}
```

I don't test this code, so if you have problem, read jQuery documentation about AJAX Requests :)

Comment: I've tried that code but for some reason it doesn't populate the `timesheets` DIV now - can you check pls?

Comment: I forgot add a parameter to callback function in $.get. Try now, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it populates fine now but when the session times-out, the login page still appears within the `timesheets` DIV rather than the whole page

Comment: so replace redirection with return statement. You can use http-response-code(http://php.net/http_response_code) too

Comment: Sorry, this looks like a really promising solution but I just can't get it to work, in the `.fail` function I'm redirecting to the login page but it doesn't seem to trigger even when it receives the 401 code.

Comment: try solution with $.ajax(answer edited), should work... You can debug your code: use console.log.